# Interpreting Typescript map function

Tags: typescript

I have an example of a map function that is provided to me in Typescript but I'm not able to interpret the function at all as i find it difficult to understand the underlying syntax.

```
function map<T,V>(func: (_:T)=>V, list: ConsList<T>): ConsList<V> {
    return list ? cons(func(head(list)), map(func, rest(list))): undefined;
}
```

To be more exact, i couldn't understand the **arguments** of the map function (func: (*:T)=>V, list: ConsList). I know that ":" represents the type of the object but what does **func:(***:T) => V is supposed to mean?

Would appreciate some help on this as I can't seem to get this.

Comment: `(_:T)=>V` is a 'fat arrow' operator that essentially means "A function that takes an argument of generic type T and returns a value of generic type V."  More info [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).